# Is there any known problems with using box-sizing?

Tags: html, css

**Problem**

I have set my CSS with;

```
*, *:before, *:after {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
     box-sizing: border-box;
     margin:0;
     padding:0
}
```

Since doing so though i have inconsistencies with the height of a div that has a set height, across different browsers.

**Div's CSS in question**

```
.content.one /*inquiry form*/ {
    position: absolute;
    float: left;
    display: none;
    top: 50px;
    height: 615px;
    left: -255px;
    width: 960px;
    z-index: 5;
    padding-left: 50px;
    padding-right: 50px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    background-color: #000000;

}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about which browsers have problems and what they are?

Comment: Firefox and Chrome display different heights in a fixed height div.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use non-standart properties to use (sad but code will become invalid, because of them :()

```
-moz-box-sizing: border-box; /* Firefox */
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari, Chrome */
```

So full style will be:

```
div {
    width: 300px;
    background: #ccc;
    padding: 20px;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari, Chrome */
    box-sizing: border-box; /* ie, opera */
}
```

Now div will be `300px` width with all margins and paddings.

One cons is `box-sizing` property doesn't work in IE6 and IE7.

You can use nested layers instead:

Html:

```
<div class="block">
    <div>I have 100% width</div>
</div>
```

Css:

```
.block { 
    width: 150;
}
.block div {
    background: #fc0;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

Source: http://htmlbook.ru/samlayout/blochnaya-verstka/blochnaya-model

Comment: Is that not what i have done already? See my css code snippet.

Comment: @DanCundy your question is `Is there any known problems with using box-sizing?`. I told you about known problem: issues in ie6 and ie7 and explained how you can avoid them. Maybe somebody will help you better, sorry.

Comment: Fair enough! I did also post a question lower on the post. But thank you anyway!

Comment: As @ExplosionPills said: `Can you be more specific about which browsers have problems and what they are?`

Comment: Firefox and Chrome display different heights on a fixed height div, it only happens when i enable the box-sizing: box-border property. when i delete the line the divs are the same across browsers. I could deletes it then resize every thing but i would rather work out why its doing it.